# Torsion points of an elliptic curve over number fields. Another proof of Silverman AEC theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am studying the following theorem from Silverman's AEC:

[image]

I am wondering whether there exists another proof that doesn't make use of formal groups and is still valid for a number field $K$. Could you suggest to me any references?

Comment: For the purpose of teaching, I use an argument like in Silverman-Tate "Rational points on elliptic curves" or in Cassels "Lectures on elliptic curves". Note however that this is really the same proof, just spelling out the argument without using the formal group. I view it more as a motivation to learn the more conceptual approach using the formal group.

Comment: if I understood the question correctly over $\mathbb{Q}$ I have a proof which presumably generalizes, check out https://people.math.harvard.edu/~alpoge/fun/nagell%20lutz.pdf . actually I put off posting that in undergrad but this convinces me that I should just put it up on the arxiv or something. I also didn’t want to use anything fancy when dealing with torsion points the first time I saw this sort of statement :P!! the proof in Silverman-Tate of Nagell-Lutz (and every other one I could find) is based on Lutz’s thesis under Weil where she proves the theorem in basically the standard way.

Comment: basically the summary is: if $(x,y)$ is $p$-torsion, then since the square of the $p$-th division polynomial has leading coefficient $p^2$ and no “trace” (one below the leading) coefficient it follows that the square of the denominator of $x$ divides the leading coefficient $p^2$. but denominators of rational points are squares, so $x$ is integral, and then everything follows. it’s gotta be the same formal groups proof under the hood, but anyway I prefer thinking that way